# Spring JPA repository transactionality

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

1 quick question on Spring JPA repositories transactionality.
I have a service that is not marked as transactional and calls Spring JPA repository method

```
userRegistrationRepository.deleteByEmail(email);
```

And it is defined as

```
@Repository
public interface UserRegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRegistration, Long> {

    UserRegistration findByEmail(String email);

    void deleteByEmail(String email);

}
```

The problem is that it fails with "*No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException*" exception.

Ok, I can solve it by marking the service **or** *deleteByEmail(..)* method as transactional, but I just can't understand why it crashes now. Spring documentation explicitly states that "*CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default.*" (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions), but apparently this one is not... So Is this statement related to only members of `CrudRepository`?

ps: that's for Spring Data JPA 1.9.4

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are right. Only CRUD methods (`CrudRepository` methods) are by default marked as transactional.
If you are using custom query methods you should explicitly mark it with `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRegistration, Long> {

    UserRegistration findByEmail(String email);

    @Transactional
    void deleteByEmail(String email);

}
```

You should also be aware about consequences of marking repository interface methods instead of service methods. If you are using default transaction propagation configuration (`Propagation.REQUIRED`) then:

> The transaction configuration at the repositories will be neglected
> then as the outer transaction configuration determines the actual one
> used.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

If you want more information about how it is implemented, take a look at default `CrudRepository` / `JpaRepository` implementation - `SimpleJpaRepository` (which you are probably using):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java

The interesting lines are here:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID> {
```

and some of transactional methods here:

```java
@Transactional
public void deleteById(ID id) {
```

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
```

Comment: In spring-data-jpa:2.0.9, there is no `@Transactional` annotation in the source code of `JpaRepository` or its ancestors - the default transactionality seems to be applied at runtime. Also note that if you put `@Transactional( ... custom properties ... )` on your repository interface, it will apply to all methods declared in your interface, and in child interfaces -- but not to any methods declared in the parent interface (`JpaRepository`) unless you redeclare them.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer `@Transactional` annotations are applied in default `JpaRepository` / `CrudRepository` implementation: `SimpleJpaRepository`
Take a look here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java 
I think you will find there all the answers :)

Comment: thanks for the correction - it's not runtime magic, simply the implementation class that's annotated. My remark about overriding is still accurate, though.