# Unable to enforce Propagation.MANDATORY on Spring Data CRUD methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, transactional, propagation

Any reason for this?

I've been using Spring data for years but I don't think I've ever unit tested one of their out-of-the-box CRUD methods before.

Why is it that the following interface definition has no effect on their transactional implementation for CRUD methods?

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    Stream<MyEntity> findMyEntityByStatusEquals(Status status);
}
```

If I call `myRepository.save(new MyEntity())` from a test method, WITHOUT my test being wrapped in a transaction, it succeeds.

However, if I call `myRepository.findMyEntityByStatusEquals("MY_STATUS")` it fails stating that it needs to be wrapped in a transaction.

The latter case I expect, the former case terrifies me as I don't seem to be able to enforce it to be part of an existing transaction.

**::Edit::** Turns out putting `@Transactional` at the top of the interface has no effect on Spring Data CRUD methods that have previously been marked as `@Transactional`. I always assumed it was also an override when specified on these interfaces.

Comment: It seems to be related to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827054/spring-jpa-repository-transactionality)

Comment: It is not the same question at all. I searched everywhere for an answer to this question before I raised it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions)

> CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default. For
> reading operations the transaction configuration readOnly flag is set
> to true, all others are configured with a plain @Transactional so that
> default transaction configuration applies.

@Transactional has Propagation.REQUIRED as its default propagation type, so when you call the `save` method a new transaction just begin.

If you want force Propagation.MANDATORY even on *built-in* CRUD methods you have to override such methods, i.e

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    Stream<MyEntity> findMyEntityByStatusEquals(Status status);

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public <MyEntity> MyEntity save(MyEntity entity) {
      super.save(entity);
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Just to add further input to this, you don't actually need to write Propagation.MANDATORY on the overridden save() method if it's already at the top of the interface in your case.