# Spring Boot test with @Sql locks tables and repositores and services cannot read

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, jhipster

I am using SQL Server 2016 as a production and development database (so no h2) with a Spring Boot 2 backend and Angular 7 frontend. If I run the application normally, everything works as intended.
For integration testing (JUnit5), I would like to use Selenium, so the application needs to actually run on a port and be accessible with a browser. I also need to prepare some data before each test (as I cannot use production data). In order to achieve both, I planned to use [spring's `@Sql` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sql), which allows me execute any `.sql` file before the tests (In my case, I insert data I would like to manipulate). Spring rolls back everything after the test, so It should work well. However, **when I am inserting data, the transaction the test started locks the database tables and the other services/repositories the application use (to query data for example) are blocked.**

Example.: I insert an employee in the file I linked in the `@Sql` annotation, then Selenium starts the browser and I navigate to a list with the employees. At this point, the employee listing won't work (which is served using a REST endpoint and the `EmployeeRepository`), because it is blocked by the test's transaction.

I can also confirm this locking manually, while the tests run, I cannot execute queries using SQL Server Management Studio (waiting and completes when I end the tests).

Can I use `@Sql` or any other data preparation tool for my tests and let the application work normally, while also being able to roll back the changes after the tests?

Test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = ...App.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Transactional
public class SeleniumExampleIT {
    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port;

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected NgWebDriver ngWebDriver;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setupClass() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setupTest() {
        var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver = chromeDriver;
        ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(chromeDriver);
        ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test
    @Sql({"classpath:sql/test.sql"})
    void listEmployeesTest() {
        //...starting selenium
        // navigating, waiting ..etc
    }
}
```

The `EmployeeRepository`:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Employee e " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH e.settings")
    List<Employee> findAll();
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Employee e " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH e.settings " +
        "WHERE e.id = :id")
    Optional<Employee> findById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Edit.: Annotating the `JpaRepository` methods with `@Transactional` did not solve the problem (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39829964/840315)).

Edit2.: According to [Spring's docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)

> If your test is @Transactional, it rolls back the transaction at the
>   end of each test method by default. However, as using this arrangement
>   with either RANDOM_PORT or DEFINED_PORT implicitly provides a real
>   servlet environment, the HTTP client and server run in separate
>   threads and, thus, in separate transactions. Any transaction initiated
>   on the server does not roll back in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to NOT use `@Transactional` tests. I created a separate database which only used for test runs. I clean the database BEFORE each test using a script like this:

```sql
-- CHECK IF DATABASE HAS TESTING ALLOWED
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.tests_allowed') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Testing is NOT allowed in the selected database! Please, check carefully, before removing all data! If you want to allow testing, create table dbo.`tests_allowed`.', 16, 1)
END;

-- DISABLE CHECKS
ALTER TABLE dbo.<table-names> NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

-- TRUNCATE TABLES
DELETE FROM dbo.<table-names>;

-- ENABLE CHECKS
ALTER TABLE dbo.<table-names> WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

After the truncate ran, I prepare the database with the data insert script, executing it like this:

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Checking settings....")
@Sql(value = {"classpath:sql/truncate-tables.sql", "classpath:sql/example-dataset-1.sql"},
    config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = SqlConfig.TransactionMode.ISOLATED))
public void check...Test() {}
```

Using the ISOLATED mode, the Sql files will be commited right away and I can read the data during the tests.

This way.:

- The database is always cleaned before the tests and I don't need to worry about dirty data during a test
- If a test fails, I can check the database in the state it failed
- Having the check before the truncate script prevents the test from running on a production or development environments (I manually add the tests_allowed table to the test db).
- Don't need to worry about Hibernate not committing data or transactions locking/deadlocking