# Springboots allows for duplicate documents to be saved

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I've been using MongoDB and Spring Boot. I created a small webapp and I seem to hit a bug. After I deploy my web app to EC2 and have everything set up, I try different scenarios. One is where me and my friend try to save the same object to the database. This should not be possible as in my code I have restricted it, so it would get an error. But somehow, if timed perfectly, we both can save the document. We use our method `contains` that checks if the document exists already but it seems to fail in this case.

```
    /**
     * @param id ID of the document we are looking for
     * @return true or false based on if the Doc with given ID exists
     */
    @Override
    public boolean contains(String id) {
        return eventModelRepo.findById(id).isPresent();
    }
```

Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the rest of of the repository code as well as the service layer?

Comment: This maybe casused based on how you are saving data. Remember `save` and  `insert` are 2 different types of actions performed on your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a use a `@Transactional` annotation to prevent concurrent write access to the database

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39829964/2588771

Comment: so all i need to do is add that annotation?

Comment: You should add it to the parent method for the entire method chain in your @repository class. So whatever method is calling contains and then calling the function to add the document should have that annotation.